# content file after Jboss deployment from war

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am a newbie. Now I am developing a project using `jBoss 7.1`. When I run the project from `Eclipse`, my application 'myproject.war' directory **exists** under the directory of 'jBoss/standalone/deployments'.

But I got some problems, when I exported war file and upload/deploy by `JBoss Admin Console`, my application 'myproject.war' directory **does not exists** under the directory of `jBoss/standalone/deployments`. Every re-deployment times, application directory path is changed under temp directory of jboss server.

**My problem is,** my application keep the user uploaded files under the a directory of application root directory (Example : `jBoss/standalone/deployments/myproject/upload`).

I need to backup the `upload` directory regularly. That's why, I want to constant path of application directory for every re-development time.

Comment: That is expected. JBoss creates temporary folders for deployments just like that. What's the question?

Comment: Thanks! I want to create a projectname.war folder under deployments folder without using Eclipse and I want all uploaded files to save there.

Comment: I dont believe you can. I feel your problem is something else. Why are you needing that in the first place?

Comment: if you deploy by hand - copy the war to the deployment folder, you will have the war there...